# Regular expression groups for multiple matches in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i am using a regular expression:  `pattern=/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.].*?)=(.*?);/g;` which has more than one match in the text i use. Now i want the content which is after "=" . I used `RegExp.$2` but it gives only one value. Please help me for getting the value after "=" in all matches available.

Comment: How are you using the regular expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to iterate through matches in a while loop:

```
var match = null;
while (match = pattern.exec(script_txt)) {
    // Do something with match[2]
}
```

Comment: It also works with RegExp.$2                                            Thankyou

Comment: Ok, this is awesome.  Will you please explain why it works?  I'd seen this technique used here before, but then couldn't find it again later.  I've looked through some documentation and couldn't find anything. Why do you get different results from the same method call against the same data? Does it only work in `while` loop?

Comment: From the [`exec` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/z908hy33(v=vs.94).aspx): If the `exec` method doesn't find a match, it returns NULL (this is why it can be put into a `while` loop). If it finds a match, it returns an array ... and modifies the global `RegExp` object. **If the global flag is set for a regular expression, `exec` searches the string beginning at the position indicated by the value of `lastIndex`**. If the global flag is not set, `exec` ... searches from the beginning of the string.

Comment: So to summarise `exec` remembers where it found the last match and continues searching from there (if the regex has the `g` switch).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Somehow I missed the bit about how the global flag effects the start position.  Glad to know it.

Comment: Old topic but this really helped me @mathematical.coffee. When using the RegExp() object to build the expression, you can set the global flag like so: `var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');`